# How could a vertical list of dropdown text be created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to understand how this sort of dropdown list could be produced, possibly without Js.

To be more clear, I'm trying to make something like this:

```
<Clickable Text Subject Name>
    <Hidden Description>
<Clickable Text Subject Name>
    <Hidden Description>
<Clickable Text Subject Name>
    <Hidden Description>
```

Whereby the "Hidden Description" shifts the elements below it, when the subject is clicked.

Also, when trying to add more than one dropdown text element, with my attempt, they are placed horizontally

My attempt:

```css
.dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <p class="dropbtn">Subject name1</p>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>The subject description in all it's glory</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have any ideas, please let me know, thanks!

Comment: If you are asking about "clicks" that requires Javascript or a checkbox hack. Which are you trying to solve...the clicking (in which you need to do more research) or the alignment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the given example of collapsible elements, so I could get what I was looking for. Here's what I'm using, based on the link I tried to provide

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function ToggleDesc(ref){
            var content = ref.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
              content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
              content.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .subject {
            border: none;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 25px;
            width: 100%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .desc {
          padding: 0 18px;
          display: none;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="subject" onClick="ToggleDesc(this)">Subject 1</button>
    <a class="desc">A very descriptive description</a>

    <button type="button" class="subject" onClick="ToggleDesc(this)">Subject 2</button>
    <a class="desc">A very descriptive description</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        let isOpen = false;

    function something() {
      isOpen = !isOpen;
      let result = isOpen ? 'block':'none'
      document.getElementById("dropdown").style.display = result;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropDownButton" onclick="something()">DROPDOWN</button>
        <div class="dropDownContent" id="dropdown">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: That's pretty close,  but it doesn't work for multiple entries. I'm looking for displaying the description of the subject that's selected.

Comment: Do you know of any site with a similar design?

Comment: I've been looking for a similar style with no luck. However! I just found out about this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_collapsible.asp which features what I've been looking for. Thankyou for the help

Comment: Did you figure it out @Luc?